# AUTODESK FORGE BIM360 WEBHOOK ISSUES ROADMAP

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-bim360, bim

We are looking into ways of visualizing Issues and Rfi’s (minimally) as geopositioned items in our GIS (Geographic Information System). We achieved some interesting results, though looking at automating the process, ideally, I would like to have data pushed to me as opposed to have to manually pull it. The obvious solution is to use Webhooks Events. A list of exposed webhooks is available here  but there is nothing related to Issues and Rfi’s. I was wondering what is the roadmap for Forge Webhooks.

1. Is there another way to achieve the same “Push” effect?
2. Is there a plan to expose Issues and Rfi’s events to Webhooks? (Creation, status, modifications…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification is something we often hear. We have a wish as a future enhancement. But I don't think it's in our radar for near future. (RFI, for example, access API itself is still to come.) We will be announcing new APIs through our newsletter or on our documentation. But feel free to check back say in 3-6 months to see where we are.
For now, we will need to check back periodically.

Comment: It looks like RFIs are now exposed in the API  as beta:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/rfis-v2-rfis-GET/

Webhooks for both issues and RFIs would be helpful!